# Horizontally order the <th> tag of a table with NodeJs and Handlebars

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

How about, I try to make a consultation with NodeJs, Mysql and Handlebars.
The result of the query I have no problem.
The table in BD is as follows.

Fruits Table

```
Id    fruit
1     Apple
2     Mango
3     Strawberry
```

The file where you made the query

Fruit.js

```
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {

  const fruitAll = await db.query('SELECT  * FROM fruit ’);

res.render(‘fruit’, {fruitAll});
});
```

The file where I perform the view is as follows.

List.hbs

```
{{#each fruitAll}}
<div class="container p-4">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>{{fruit}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Example 1</th>
      <th>Example 2</th>
      <th>Example 3</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

The result is as follows:

```
--------------
Apple
--------------
Example 1
--------------
Mango
--------------
Example 2
--------------
Strawberry
--------------
Example 3
--------------
```

What I would like is how to place the fruits horizontally. I mean this way.

```
______________________________
|Apple   |Mango   | Strawberry|
_______________________________
|Example1|Example2| Example3  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be:

```
<div class="container p-4">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
     {{#each fruitAll}}
      <th>{{fruit}}</th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Example 1</th>
      <th>Example 2</th>
      <th>Example 3</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Because you need MORE `th` tags. In your case `<div>..</div>` is replicated `fruitAll.length`(in this case 3) time.